# Break a <tr> using only CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am looking for a way to "break" a table row using only CSS.

I want to change this:
[image: one line]

To this:
[image: broken line]

I don't have access to the HTML, but can control the CSS.

I have tried

```
td:nth-child(3) {
    display: block;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Here is some simplified code for testing:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style>
td:nth-child(3) {
    display: block;
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>111111</td>
        <td>222222</td>
        <td>333333</td>
        <td>444444</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can give the `tr` a `width` and all the `td` half the width of the `tr` and a `float:left;`. Something like this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfhA6/)

Comment: Is this for responsiveness purposes (to control the appearance with media queries or something)? To include the tag in the question, this is a ver useful one.

Comment: This isn't possible without losing other attributes tables present you with, that is, their unique resizing characteristics.

Comment: I would not use a table in this case, but rather flexbox or css grid.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

How about using `inline-block` with a fixed `width` table...  Or using `%` roughly `45%` of `width` for your `td` elements so you won't need to define `width` for the `table`

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/psJ6A/)</kbd>

Here, am just turning the `td` to `display: inline-block;` and because of the fixed `width` table, they will be forced to wrap to the next line.

Also am using `word-wrap: break-word;` property so that non spaced strings are forced to break.

```
table {
    width: 120px;
}

table tr td {
    width: 50px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

table tr td {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

You can use `%` based `width` as well, so that you don't need to care about the cell widths....

You might need `vertical-align: top;` along with `min-height` if in case a cell is blank in your `table`

```
table tr td {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 2px;
    vertical-align: top;
    min-height: 20px;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/psJ6A/3/)</kbd> *(Only required if a cell is blank)*

---

Just note that `inline-block` will cause some issues with `4px` offset, in this case just assign `font-size: 0;` to the `table` and re-set the `font-size` back for your `td` element, this way you will get consistency in cell margin.

> Warning: I would never ever recommend to do such types of things, so
>   keep this as your last priority. If you have JavaScript control, than
>   consider appending `tr` around the `td`

---

From here onwards **please ignore** if you cannot use jQuery, say suppose you have an using jQuery library you can simply add the snippet to that JS file....

*(Am adding a `class` here to uniquely identify the element, `class` can also be added using `.addClass()` by defining some nearest CSS selector)* so no question of modifying the HTML here.

```
$('table.wrap_trs tr').unwrap(); //Remove default pre-generated tr
var cells = $('table.wrap_trs tr td');
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i += 2) {
    cells.slice(i, i + 2).wrapAll('<tr></tr>'); //Wrapping the tds with tr
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/psJ6A/2/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the jQuery solution, for the users who can use it :)

Comment: "roughly 45%" can be done better if you use `box-sizing:border-box` (and the corresponding `-moz-box-sizing:border-box`) and use `width:50%`... unless you have margins, in which case you'll need to subtract those manually.

Comment: Thank you so much! I managed to do that with only the width and display:inline-block properties, the other seem unnecessary.

Answer (score 8):

You may use float property and play with width of TD as you need to adjust border width of table

```
table{
        width:100%;
    }

td:nth-child(3) {
    display: block;
    background-color: yellow;
}


tr td {
    float: left;
    width: 49.5%;
}
```

Hope this helps! but need to check browser compatibility

Comment: Thank you. This works, but seem to be harder to adjust to my needs than the top answer.

Comment: I agree this is because 1) cellpadding and cellmargin need to be 0 but you haven't got access to table html markup 2) also placing fix width in px may brek your layout in future if text size increases

Answer (score 5):

Proper CSS Method, Simple and Easy

This may help you , but it may create problem for variable length , hence i have used min-width

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>

    td:nth-child(3) {
        display: block;
        background-color: yellow;
        clear:left;
    }
    tr{
    float:left;
    }
    td{
    float:left;
    min-width:100px; //used min-width for proper alignment
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>111111</td>
            <td>222222</td>
            <td>333333</td>
            <td>444444</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Very good! The min-width and clear:left seem to prevent elements from flying around. Thanks for that.